# DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect No object manager was set

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework3

I'm trying to add 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect' to my forms but it keeps given me this error: No object manager was set

this is the code for my forms:

```
use Zend\Form\Form;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
use Retrieve\Entity\Autos;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use DoctrineModule\Persistence\ObjectManagerAwareInterface;

class AddForm extends Form
{ 
  /**
 * Entity manager.
 * @var Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager 
 */
private $entityManager;

protected $objectManager;

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct('addforms');

    $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');

    $this->addElements();
    $this->addInputFilter();  

}

protected function addElements() 
{           
    // Add "title" field
    $this->add([        
        'type'  => 'text',
        'name' => 'title',
        'attributes' => [
            'id' => 'title'
        ],
        'options' => [
            'label' => 'Title',
        ],
    ]);

 $this->add([
        'type' => 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect',
        'name' => 'country',
        'options' => [
            'label' => 'Country',
            'object_manager' =>  $this->getObjectManager(),
            'target_class'   => 'BusinessGhana\Entity\Country',
            'property'       => 'country',
            'display_empty_item' => true,
            'empty_item_label'   => '--select Country--',                
        ],
    ]); 
  //other elements here...
}

 public function setObjectManager(ObjectManager $objectManager)
{
    $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
}

public function getObjectManager()
{
    return $this->objectManager;
} 

private function addInputFilter() 
{  
    //  inputfilter elements here...  
}
}
```

Can someone guide me on how to solve this problem.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your class form should implements `ObjectManagerAwareInterface`.

```
class AddForm extends Form implements ObjectManagerAwareInterface
{

}
```

Because class that instance of `ObjectManagerAwareInterface` will be injected `ObjectManager` from `setObjectManager()` method.

Comment: I already tried that (implements ObjectManagerAwareInterface), and it gives same error; no object manager was set.

Comment: We are normally supposed to instantiate the form by using FormElementManager instead of direct class creation, and then also use init() instead of __construct as it is shown in the official document - https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/4.1.x/docs/form-element.md, and it makes sense. However, I can't make it work no matter what I did (Laminas) for the last couple of hours to solve this.. setObjectManager() method is never executed, so there is no object manager injected. Found this thread online, so wanted to check if any solution from the past :)